# Zerotier and printer

Tags: networking, printing, network-bridge

I have a private Zerotier SD-WAN (10.99.99.0/24). Some of my clients also use a local net 192.168.0.0/24. And there is also a network printer with 192.168.0.101.

Since Zerotier does not have a client for this printer my question is: How can I make this printer available in the Zerotier network (10.99.99.0/24). So that I can use it from all my Zerotier clients.

Here is the network config of such a client:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:60:7b:ed:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.211/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    
22: zt7zkupgbd: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2800 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:33:17:aa:f8:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.99.99.211/24 brd 10.99.99.255 scope global zt7zkupgbd
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution with Internet Redirection Server (rinetd) but with additional hardware.

I set up a raspberry and installed

```
apt install rinetd
```

Then I installed zerotier client and joined the zerotier network. Then  forwarded all printer ports to my actual printer 192.168.0.101